How do I change the Ubuntu Server Wi-Fi SSID and password
I have Ubuntu server on an old laptop which I built at home, connected to my home Wi-Fi.
This is a portable server and during the course of the day I change the location and I need to connect to a new Wi-Fi SSID from the command line.
All of the options I can find suggest using apt to load some new software to access some functionality.
Problem is apt is not going to play untill I have a Wi-Fi connection.
Now the SSID and password has to be stored either in grub or somewhere in the current file structure.
It's ironic: I have a 4G Wi-Fi hotspot that I can use anywhere if I can only get the server to see it.
I need the solution to be command line, without a current Wi-Fi connection and it has to be possible hey you can do it with a couple of clicks from a GUI.
OK if the solution is in a text file, it makes the server easy to hack on the network but it's my network and it's only available when I am online.
If push comes to shove I will do a full instalation using the 4G hotspot but I am only going to have to change this when I am on my home Wi-Fi or conected to some other remote Wi-Fi.

Did you install nmcli?

The network configuration file on Ubuntu is a YAML file located in the /etc/netplan directory. The default name of the configuration file is 00-installer-config.yaml
Step 1: open the network configuration file using your favorite text editor, replace the contents of the configuration file with the following template. Make sure you change the following details:

Wi-Fi interface name: Replace the interface name wlp0s20f3, with the correct Wi-Fi interface name you obtained by the following ls command to list all your network interfaces:   ls -l /sys/class/net. Wi-Fi interface cards start with the letter w. In this case, the Wi-Fi interface card name is wlp0s20f3. Your system will probably have a different name, so take note of that.
Access points: Change the access point names provided here with the correct ones. Mywifi1 and Mywifi2 are the Wi-Fi networks your server is configured to connect to by default.
Password: Update the password for each Wi-Fi network. 


Save the changes you've made and close the configuration file.
Step 2: Apply your changes using the following command:
sudo netplan apply

Alternatively, you can reboot your system and the changes will be automatically applied once the system boots.

How to Connect to a Wi-Fi Network on Ubuntu Server
